# The convergence of a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

A sequence $\{A_n : n=0,1,2,...\}$ is said to be *monotone nondecreasing* if we have
$$A_0\subseteq A_1\subseteq \cdot \cdot \cdot \subseteq A_n \subseteq \cdot \cdot \cdot $$

The same sequence is said to be *monotone nonincreasing* if we have

$$A_0\supseteq A_1\supseteq \cdot \cdot \cdot \supseteq A_n \supseteq \cdot \cdot \cdot$$
To specify the type of convergence, for a *monotone nondecreasing* sequence of set we write we write $\{A_{n}\}\uparrow A$, likewise for a *monotone nonincreasing* sequence we write $\{A_{n}\}\downarrow A$.

I am confused by the notation, does the latter statement about convergence imply that $\bigcup \{A_n\}=A$? Or, does it only mean that the as $n\to\infty$ the $n$-th element of $\{A_n\}$ will get closer and closer to the some set $A$ (not necessarily $\bigcup\{A_n\}$) but it will never be equal to $A$ because the sequence is infinite?

Comment: For a non-increasing sequence, you have $\lim A_n = \bigcap A_n$.

Comment: "Closer and closer to some set $A$" doesn't mean anything in the world of sets.  I can't think of anything these limits could mean besides union and intersection.

Comment: @DanielFischer  So, $\{A\}\downarrow=\bigcap A_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The down- and up-arrows imply the monotonicity of the sequence; the $A$ is the actual limit, which is the intersection for a non-increasing sequence and the union for a non-decreasing sequence.

If $\langle A_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is monotone non-increasing, then its limit is $$A=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\;,$$ and we write $$\langle A_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\downarrow A\;.$$ If the sequence is monotone non-decreasing, then its limit is $$A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n\;,$$ and we write $$\langle A_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\uparrow A\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am still a little confused; If $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$
  then $A\subseteq A_{0},A_{1},...$
 , since the sequence $\{A_{n}\}$
  is monotone non-increasing does this mean that $A_{\infty}=A$
 ?

Comment: @Jimmy: There is no $A_\infty$: we have only $A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. You could decide to call the limit $A_\infty$ instead of $A$, if you wished, but you’d be applying the name yourself: there is no $A_\infty$ in the sets that you’re given.

Comment: I think that I am starting to get it. But one last inquisition, either way if a sequence is monotone non-increasing or monotone non-decreasing, we have that every element in the sequence is a subset of its limit right?

Comment: @Jimmy: That’s true for a non-decreasing sequence; if the sequence is non-increasing, then each $A_n$ in the sequence is a **superset** of the limit, i.e., the limit is a subset of each $A_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is all starting to come together now. I am working on one of the exercises now I will post it  when I finish.

Comment: @Jimmy: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Often the general notion of "limit" of a sequence of sets $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is defined by saying

1. $x \in \lim_n A_n$ if $x \in A_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$
2. $x \notin \lim_n A_n$ if $x \notin A_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

If there is some $x$ such that the truth value of "$x \in A_n$" is not eventually constant, then the limit is not defined.

This is the appropriate definition because it makes the characteristic function of $\lim_n A_n$ equal to the pointwise limit of the characteristic functions of the $A_n$'s (and undefined when this pointwise limit is undefined.)

One can show that if the sequence is monotone then the limit exists and is equal to the union (if the sequence is increasing) or the intersection (if the sequence is decreasing.)  These are special cases of the general definition.

Comment: hi do you have any book where this type of definition is used/introduced?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be stated somewhere that the union of all $A_n$ is $A$ in the monotone nondecreasing case, and that in the monotone nonincreasing case, the intersection of all $A_n$ is $A$. It would have to be *defined* this way, not proved this way, so you should look to your book to make sure this is the definition given!

If it is defined this way, as it likely is, then in the nondecreasing case $\bigcup A_n=A$ is correct. If you're having trouble understanding this statement, it can be transformed into a set theoretic one: $x\in A$ iff $\exists n$ such that $x\in A_n$. In the nonincreasing case, we have $A=\bigcap A_n$ meaning $x \in A$ iff $\forall n, x\in A_n$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. The book actually does not mentions any of the above, perhaps it assumes that I already knew this.